# Check for class or name instead of ID (simple code)

Tags: jquery, class, visible

I am new to jQuery and have created a little code snippet to check if any (i.e. one or more) of the following IDs is visible on a form.

The code works fine but I was wondering if I could achieve the same by checking for a class or name that I could assign to each ID so that it could also handle more IDs and I dont have to mention each of them separately.

Can someone here help me with this and tell me how to write it properly.

**My Code (working):**

```
if(($('#fail1').is(':visible')) || ($('#fail2').is(':visible')) || ($('#fail3').is(':visible')))
{
    // do something;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of behaviour a class is meant for - duplicating logic over a set of elements. It's possible to use an `id` attribute selector in jQuery although these are relatively slow and should be used as a last resort.

All you need to do is give the class to your elements and amend your code like this:

```
if ($('.fail').is(':visible')) {
    alert('at least one element is visible');
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PHSur/)

Comment: Was about to write this exact solution, +1

Comment: This works perfect and I got the logic. Thanks a lot for the fast reply !

Answer (score 2):

```
if($( "[id^='fail']" ).is(':visible') )
{
    // do something;
}
```

reference  **[attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. This works fine too - I just went for the option above here.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, jQuery is not required to do that:

```
if (Array.prototype.some.call(document.querySelectorAll('.fail'), function (n) {
      return (window.getComputedStyle(n).display !== 'none');
    })) {
    console.log('at least one element is visible');
}
```